# How to handle connection errors when accessing a server in python?

Tags: python, server, copy, connection

I regularly have to copy files to/from a server; I use `shutil.move()` for that. Most of the time it works well but every once in a while I receive connection errors as the server doesn't respond. How do I best handle this issue?

Comment: Depends on the result you want to have. First you have to catch the error (try-except). Then you could wait some time and try it again or you write the incident to a log file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.